# Handling shared/tmp in a Ruby on Rails project when the deploy user is different than the run user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, capistrano

I have two users on my server, an Ubuntu 12.04 virtual server that I manage myself:

- projectx is used to deploy the application and is the user/group for most files in /var/www/projectx
- projectx_rails and it's used to run the Rails application. That way, the running rails application doesn't have access to modify the source code.

Some directories, like public/uploads, are configured to belong to projectx_rails:projectx_rails, so that the rails app can write the uploaded files.

My problem comes to the directory tmp. This directory is located in /var/www/projectx/shared and linked to each release in the usual capistrano way of handling releases. The problem is that some files created during deployment are then not writable by the running rails app and files created by the rails app are not writable by the deployment process.

Is there a way to handle this? Having all the files there belong to projectx_rails:projectx_rails and be group writable would be good enough, but I'm not sure how to trigger this.

I'm using: Capistrano 3, Rails 3.2, Ruby 2.1.2, Unicorn 4.8.3, nginx.

Comment: This is probably going to require some permission/umask work in the rails process and the capistrano user, so it will depend on your server platform, your app server, and possibly your web server. Can you update with these details?

Comment: @gwcoffey I added those details, I think. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: One more question: Does your capistrano recipe actually create files in tmp, or is the problem that it runs rake tasks that can't *read* files from tmp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is my theory. It is obviously hard to test on my end, so consider it conjecture.

**First:** make a group that both users belong to. Like `projectx_shared`.

**Second:** make this group the group owner of the `tmp` directory:

```
chown projectx_rails:projectx_shared tmp
```

**Third:** set the *setgid* bit on this directory:

```
chmod g+s tmp
```

Now, the group owner of files added to `tmp` should be set to `projectx_shared` automatically. I *think* this will apply to capistrano tasks as well.

I'm assuming when you deploy, files already get `rw-rw-r--` permissions automatically. If not, you'll need to set your UMASK to 002 in your, e.g. `.bashrc` as well.

Let me know if it works...

Comment: Can you change the umask for the deploy user in .bashrc? Make sure you put it before any check for interactive shells.

Comment: Do I really need the shared group? wouldn't making the user projectx belong to projectx_rails enough (as user projectx belongs to the group projectx_rails).

Comment: Technically no. It just seemed weird to me to put one user in another user's group. Putting them both into a new group seems more explicitly in line what what you're trying to accomplish. But it will work (theoretically) either way.

Comment: It does work, but it required watching out for many things: upstart jobs define their own umask, carrierwave completely ignores the umask and assigns whatever permissions you want to files, the asset pipeline makes some files read only, even with umask 0002.

Comment: I'm glad it sorted out. I had a feeling there would be a lot of fiddling. Is it all working for you now?

Answer (score 2):

May be use ACL for shared files? The only thing that, enable ACL support in fstab.

```
setfacl -m d:u:projectx:rwx,u:projectx:rwx,\
d:u:projectx_rails:rwx,u:projectx_rails:rwx /var/www/projectx/shared/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run commands on the remote machine through capistrano. You could run a directory owner change after, lets say, symlinking the application.

In your `deploy.rb` file, add a callback for it:

```
after 'deploy:create_symlink' do
  run "chown -R projectx_rails:projectx_rails #{current_release}/tmp"
end
```

Comment: The directory is created by the user set up in your capistrano file. If that user is `projectx` you don't need to use `sudo` to change the owner to `projectx_rails`

Comment: `chown` requires sudo, `chmod` doesn't

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is to have this task:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Fix permissions"
  task :fix_permissions do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "sudo chown -R projectx_rails:projectx_rails #{shared_path}/tmp"
      execute "sudo chmod ug+rwX,o+rw #{shared_path}/tmp"
    end
  end
end
```

and run it both at the beginning and the end of my deployment:

```
after "deploy:started", "deploy:fix_permissions"
before "deploy:restart", "deploy:fix_permissions"
```

and to make it work I had to add this to my sudoers:

```
projectx ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/chown -R projectx_rails\:projectx_rails /var/www/projectx/shared/tmp
projectx ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod ug+rwX\,o+rw /var/www/projectx/shared/tmp
```

which makes me rather uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

1) ensure both projectx and projectx_rails are members of the group projectx
2) add this to deploy:

```
task :change_tmp_pems do
   run "chmod -Rf 775 #{shared_path}/tmp"
end
after "deploy:started", :change_tmp_pems
```

the -f will silently fail / skip any files it doesn't have access to, so that wont be an issue.

4 lines of code, pretty succinct.
Dont messa about with chown as it requires sudo normally and is unnecessary.